# Perl script launched with .vbs - problems with "Program Files" in path env variable

Tags: perl, vbscript

I'm launching a perl build script with a .vbs file, however when the perl window is executed it gives me "Can't find cl.exe, no such file or directory"

Running the perl script directly gives no errors. Visual studio bin folder is in my path

Any suggestions? Build script is a standard perl invoking multiple programs, .vbs script below

```
Dim ss
Set ss = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
ss.CurrentDirectory = "MyBuildDirectory"
ss.run build.pl, 1, True
```

Answer (score 2):

Look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5fk67ky%28v=vs.84%29.aspx).

Did you notice that the first argument is given as `strCommand`? That means it's a *string*. What's an *unquoted* `build.pl`?

I'm not sure why it gives you the error it does, but I know that it's probably looking for an object named 'build' and trying to get the property named 'pl'.

Comment: Sorry I re-wrote the script here for simplicity, it is actually a string in the script which is declared elsewhere

Answer (score 0):

Pure Voodoo, but try

```
iRet = ss.Run("%comspec% /c ""f:\ullpathto\perl.exe"" ""f:\ullpathto\build.pl""", 1, True)
```

If it 'works' you can delete redundant parts/pathes.

(I **believe** that the error message proves that the process started by .Run does not have the path to cl.exe)